# How to change password in ActiveMQ Classic 6.0.0?

Tags: activemq-classic

How can I change default credentials (admin/admin) in ActiveMQ Classic 6.0.0? It doesn't have `jetty-realm.properties` where credentials are set. I tried to put the file `jetty-realm.properties`, but it did not work.

Comment: @justin's comment is correct. The usernames and passwords were combined for messaging and http services to reduce administrative overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was changed via [AMQ-8391](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-8391). Modify `users.proprerties` instead.

Comment: It's working. Thx.